# Azure Cosmos MongoDB Version 4.x availability

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We run a application outside of Azure that uses MongoDB 4.0 features.
Currently we're on the migration to Azure and therefore need a Database that provides MongoDB 4.0.
Are there any plans for CosmosDB to support MongoDB 4.0?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it seems like it either 1) belongs on another Stack Exchange network (maybe dba?) 2) belongs in Azure's help center questions 3) will lead to too many opinion based answers

Comment: I posted this question here because the Azure CosmosDB documentation page states: "Ask questions and get support from Microsoft engineers and Azure community experts on Stack Overflow, ..."

Comment: Hello, Cosmos DB product guy here. Can you specify which 4.0 features you need? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use an actual MongoDB 4.0 (or newer) managed service on Azure, [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/azure-mongodb) is available now. Cosmos provides emulation for a subset of MongoDB features and API, but is a different server implementation.

Comment: @MarkBrown: Currently we're using 'multi-document tTransactions'.

Comment: @Stennie: Unfortunately only CosmosDb is approved in our company, Atlas not (yet) ...